# Select from 1 table where conditions are in another table?

Tags: sql

Here is my table in my database:

```
table1             table2    
---------|--------  --------|
UserID   |Type      UserID  |
---------|--------  --------|
user1    |Busy       user1  |
user2    |Free       user2  |
user3    |Free       user3  |
user4    |Busy       user4  |
```

I would like to select all the userID from table1 where the Type=Free. The only correlation from one table to another is that they have the same UserID in both tables.

What I have so far is :

```
SELECT UserID
FROM Data.Users
INNER JOIN Data.UserType
ON Data.Users.UserID=Data.UserType.UserID
```

This only gives me back ALL the userID where the UserID from table 1 = UserID from table 2.

I would like to be able to make it also check for the user type. Something like

```
SELECT Username FROM Data.Users WHERE TABLE2.UserID = TABLE1.UserID AND                        
TABLE2.UserType = "free"
```

I'm new to SQL so I don't think I'm Googling the right thing as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your query is working you just need to filter it:

```
SELECT Data.Users.Name
FROM Data.Users
INNER JOIN Data.UserType
ON Data.Users.UserID=Data.UserType.UserID
WHERE Data.UserType.Type = 'Free'
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. What if I wanted to select a few more values from a 3rd table, where the userID is also the same as the other 2 tables?

Lets say the 3rd table is called UserFavorites, and I want to select FavoriteLink and FavoriteType where the userID are the same as table 1 and 2?

Comment: When you have such columns that reference other columns in other tables, the option is always 1 or more joins.

Comment: Ahh okay, I just tried it out. I just needed more JOIN statement. I need to read up on it

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure you are first selecting the data that you want, in this case "Type". So that's all we need to be concerned with when selecting information. However, for illustration purposes (and general good etiquette) lets also select the userID, but we'll take this from table1.

So we want to select Type from Table 2, and UserID from table 1, but where UserID is the same on both tables.

To do what we need to do the following:

```
SELECT two.Type, one.UserID FROM table2 two INNER JOIN table1 one ON two.UserID = one.UserID
```

This selects the information, from table2 and we assign it the reference two. Then we join table1 and assign the reference one. We can then grab the requested information in the select using the references we assigned, whilst also ensuring the data is joined where the two tables have identical values.

The above example will select all values where the userID's match, and is used for illustration purposes. Then, to narrow it down, all you have to do is specify the WHERE value on top of this. So:

```
SELECT two.Type, one.UserID FROM table2 two INNER JOIN table1 one ON two.UserID = one.UserID WHERE two.Type = "Free"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the detailed explanation.